# Disabling Internet Explorer Enhanced Security

Tags: internet-explorer, windows

I'm trying to uninstall Internet Explorer Enhanced Security on Windows Server 2003. After I remove it from Windows Components and check it on a user, I'm still getting the annoying popups. Does anyone know how to completely uninstall this feature or just turn off the annoying popups?

Comment: Is this Windows Server 2003 machine acting as a terminal services machine?

Comment: Also interested in the answer to this question, otherwise you shouldn't be browsing the web from a server.

Comment: 1st. I have the same problem
2nd. Sometimes its helpful to surf update.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the server been restarted since the Enhanced Security component?  The method suggested has always worked for me, but a restart was necessary I believe.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this blog post on how to disable Internet Explorer enhanced security configuration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/06/23/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-on-windows-2003-server-silently.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT use any software being an Administrator!!! All the annoyance will be gone ;)

Answer (score -1):

MY_computer>>CTRL pannel>>Add/Remove Software>> Windows Components>>Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration>>Remove/uncheck/uninstall...etc..etc NEXT NEXT blah blah

Comment: http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-server-2008/how-to-disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-ie-esc-in-windows-server-20082003/

Comment: It would seem that Jacob has already tried that, but is still getting the security warning popups.